# Schedule re-occuing task whilst in background state. (iOS)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, scheduled-tasks

If my research is correct when your application is in the background it is really suspended. Apple supported methods for background task are location, audio, & SIP type applications is this correct?

Is there any Apple supported methods for running a method every 60 seconds whilst in background, I need to check the status of a server. The following code does what I need but stops after 10mins which I believe is another Apple supported method. Any suggestions or confirmation as to whether this is or is not possible would be helpful.

The code below just creates a task that runs every 10 seconds and updates the badge count.

Regards

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    count=0;
    counterTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                   beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
                       // If you're worried about exceeding 10 minutes, handle it here
                  }];
    theTimer=[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:5
                                             target:self
                                           selector:@selector(countUp)
                                            userInfo:nil
                                            repeats:YES];
}

- (void)countUp {
    NSLog(@"%s - %d", __FUNCTION__, count + 1 );

    if (count==1000) {
        [theTimer invalidate];
        [theTimer release];
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:counterTask];
    } else {
        count++;
        NSString *currentCount;
        currentCount=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",count];
         [currentCount release];
        [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = count;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I am using this 10 minute background task in my app also and from the research I've done this is the only way to run methods in the background. Hope that answers your question